Безопасно и стабильно ли хранить токен в памяти Python-приложения?
Есть API-proxy приложение, которое забирает на себя поддержку регистрации на другом API-сервере. Регистрация заключается в получении токена доступа через вызов API-метода с логином/паролем. Логин и пароль хранятся в .ini файле на сервере и парсятся через ConfigParser. А уже полученный по ним токен доступа к API хранится в памяти приложения + его нужно каждые 2 часа обновлять.
Для этого есть экземпляр class Register, который импортируется в нужные части приложения, и через его @property другие модули получают токен, хранящийся в _api_key:
class Register():
    USER = None
    PASSWORD = None
    def __init__(self):
        self._fill_settings()
        self._api_key = None

    # функция для заполнения _api_key
    def register_api():
        # код
    
    @property
    def api_key(self):
        return self._api_key

Про хранение заранее известных секретов сказано многое в данном ответе - но не рассмотрен случай хранения токена в памяти приложения.
Для контекста - приложение запускается в Docker-контейнере и крутится 24/7
Насколько такой способ безопасен и стабилен? Или всё же лучше запись в файл / переменные окружения?

Главное следите, что бы то, куда вы далее помещаете этот токен, в заголовки запроса например, никогда не печаталось, не выводилось в логи и не дай бог, не возвращалось в ответах на какие нибудь запросы к вашему сервису. Т.е. если вы положили его в загловки запроса, а потом для отладки вывели в логи весь запрос с заголовками, то вот она утечка. А так в памяти процесса он более защищен, чем файл на диске. файл гораздо проще найти и прочитать, чем копаться в памяти процесса в поисках токенов

Спасибо за советы - вроде как по ним должно быть всё хорошо и токен нигде не логируется / отсылается! Разве что перепроверить встроенное логирование библиотеки aiohttp. Только вот ещё остался интерес по стабильности хранения в памяти Python - какие риски, что с памятью что-то произойдет и данные потеряться могут? Обновляться каждые 2 часа токен будет спустя время, а сейчас он единоразово при запуске получается. Интересно насколько сам Python обеспечивает стабильность хранения данных.

Ну если бы из переменных что то само пропадало, то все программы бы периодически валились непредсказуемым образом :) Что касается обновления, то токен может даже не получать на старте. Делаете рядом с токеном переменную с его временем жизни, изначально выставляя его в 0 (ну или в 1970 год если оно у вас datetime будет) В функции api_key проверяете, если время жизни меньше текущего то получаете токен заново, время жизни обновляете на текущее + 2 часа. Собственно все, токены получаются по мере необходимости
